# Android EditText and large amount of text

Tags: android, android-edittext, large-data

I work on some application with ability to edit text files. But I have serious problem with EditText. Currently I load text file of size 17KB. I don't think, that 17KB is terrible amount of text. Scrolling is fine, but when I focus EditText and start edit, it has delay/freezing for 4-5 seconds. The same happends when I leave EditText. I'm using API level 8. and here is my layout for edittext :

```
    <EditText android:id="@+id/journal_text"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:lines="20"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                >

                <requestFocus />

            </EditText>
```

Here is my java code :

```
    edit = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.journal_text);
    edit.setText(readFile(path));
```

that's all

From GooglePlay I've downloaded app Jota text editor and it works perfectly with large text data...Can anyone help me please or direct me how to solve this problem?
Thank you
Anton

Comment: Are there any listeners on the `EditText`? Just trying to rule out native widget performance

Comment: In addition to listeners, does changing the keyboard make a difference?  The IME may be processing the text of the editor for word frequencies.

Comment: No, my editText does not have any listener. I'm using HackersKeyboard from market. When I change to other IME (dpad) , it is a bit better, but delay is still about 3-4 seconds :(

Comment: Hmmm...When I change android:lines="20" to android:lines="5" than performance is rapidly better....but this is not what I want. I need to have almost fullscreen edittext. On tablets "notepad" with 5 lines will be very small:(

Comment: How about a [custom edit text](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/NoteEditor.htm) as one defined here? Not sure if it will improve performance though :(

Comment: Thank you, I will implement custom edittext when there will be no other way, ...i'm trying to avoid it now, because I have a lot of work with other parts of app...

Answer (score 0):

Custom EditText will not solve the problem. Editing in EditText will become slower when the text content inside it become too large. Try to use WebView instead of EditText. It will perfectly work for a very large text content also.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use scanner to read text file.

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(tempFile).useDelimiter("\\Z");
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
stringBuilder .append(scanner.next());
}

edit.setText(stringBuilder );
```